# Trying to port ILColorPicker to an iPad app

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am trying to port ILColorPicker to an iPad app which is using Storyboards.

I put a UIView in a UIViewController; in that UIView I have 3 other UIViews (in grey below, the containing UIView has a black background, which gives it the borders).
[image]

Each of the 3 views have connections that match the sample.

This image of the connections is for the top UIView.
[image]

This is the image of the connections for the middle UIView
[image]

This is the image of the connections for the bottom UIVIew
[image]

When I run the app in the simulator, and click on the menu tab button for this controller, I get nothing but a black screen.  In addition, I put a NSLog in "viewDidLoad" and it goes through there six (6) times!

I have been working on this for over a week now, and have reached the end of what my experience and knowledge can help me.  Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong here?  I would really, really appreciate it.  (Code will be provided if needed; just didn't want to write a book here!) :D

UPDATE:  code for "viewDidLoad"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    //  Build a random color to show off setting he color on the iPad
    UIColor *c = [UIColor colorWithRed:(arc4random()%100)/100.0f
                                 green:(arc4random()%100)/100.0f
                                 blue:(arc4random()%100)/100.0f
                                 alpha:1.0];

    colorChip.backgroundColor = c;
    colorPicker.color = c;
    huePicker.color = c;
}
```

UPDATE 2: code for "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The problem might be in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your AppDelegate. Can you post that on the question as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your delegates are set to, but you should connect them to a controller rather than a view. With that said are you sure your IBOutlets are connected, I use assertions to check.

From a blank storyboard project with a single view + view controller I skel'ed something similar to what you have, here's what I got:

```
  // ViewController.h
  @protocol MyPickerDelegate <NSObject>
  - (void)myPickerDidPick:(id)sender;
  - (void)myPickerPickColor:(id)sender color:(UIColor*)color;
  @end

  @interface ViewController : UIViewController<MyPickerDelegate>
  @property (weak) IBOutlet __weak UIView *colorBar;
  @property (weak) IBOutlet __weak UIView *saturationBrightnessPicker;
  @property (weak) IBOutlet __weak UIView *huePicker;
  @end
```

and

```
  // ViewController.m
  @interface ViewController () {
    __weak UIView *colorBar_;
    __weak UIView *saturationBrightnessPicker_;
    __weak UIView *huePicker_;
  }
  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  @synthesize colorBar = colorBar_;
  @synthesize saturationBrightnessPicker = saturationBrightnessPicker_;
  @synthesize huePicker = huePicker_;

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSAssert(colorBar_, @"colorBar not connected");
    NSAssert(saturationBrightnessPicker_, @"saturationBrightnessPicker not connected");
    NSAssert(huePicker_, @"huePicker not connected");

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];  
    colorBar_.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    saturationBrightnessPicker_.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    huePicker_.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  }

  - (void)myPickerDidPick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Did pick");
  }

  ...

  @end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Matt.. I apologize for not getting back to you earlier... I was trying to get another app ready for the App Store.  That's done, so I am working on this "dog" again!  I created a new view controller (named NewViewController), copied your code and set the property of the scene.  This is the error I am now getting:

'[<NewViewController 0x6ab9f70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key colorChip.'

I have no idea what the problem is now...

Comment: ensure you have a member and property called colorChip (ie: not colour or color_)

Comment: Thanks Matt... this thing is bigger than both of us!  I am going to have to set it aside for a bit while I try to re-design the app so I don't have the color picker.  I appreciate all of the time you spent on this.

Comment: no problem! I was leaving my old job and had plenty of lame-duck time :)